# Como recorrer y mostrar sólo los elementos en la.posicion 0 y 1, 1 y 2, así sucesivamente

Tags: java

Tengo un arreglo estático de tamaño 6 y necesito  mostrar el primer elemento con el segundo, el segundo con el tercero, el tercero con el cuarto y así hasta terminar el arreglo

```
    double x;
    double y;


    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    Punto[] puntos = new Punto[6];

    puntos[0] = new Punto (4,2);
    puntos[1] = new Punto (6,8);
    puntos[2] = new Punto (45,0);
    puntos[3] = new Punto (3,3);
    puntos[4] = new Punto (2,21);
    puntos[5] = new Punto (8,14);
    for(int i=0; i<puntos.length; i++){
            System.out.println(puntos[i].coordenadas());
    }

    for(int i=0; i<puntos.length; i++ ){
            for(int j=1;j <puntos.length; j++){

            if(j>i && j != j+1){
            System.out.println("La distancia del punto "+i +" con respecto del punto " +j+ " es de: " +puntos[i].distanciaA(puntos[j]));
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Intente recorrerlo como a una matriz pero me va a evaluar con todos los demás elementos y de resultado me da 
el 0 con el 1,
el 0 con el 2,
y asi...
solo quiero que se muestre 
el 0 con el 1,
el 1 con el 2,
el 3 con el 4,
el 4 con el 5

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias ser mas especifico con lo que queres? que intentaste? que tenes?

Comment: Y no sería más fácil mostrar a cada vuelta de bucle, la posición de 'i' y la posición de 'i+1'. `puntos[i].coordenadas() + " " + puntos[i+1].coordenadas()`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que con algo así tal y como te mencionan arriba bastaría.

Añadir que el Scanner no es necesario si no va a ser utilizado.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x;
   double y;
    punto[] puntos = new punto[6];

    puntos[0] = new punto (4,2);
    puntos[1] = new punto (6,8);
    puntos[2] = new punto (45,0);
    puntos[3] = new punto (3,3);
    puntos[4] = new punto (2,21);
    puntos[5] = new punto (8,14);

    for(int i=0; i<puntos.length; i++){
            System.out.println(puntos[i].coordenadas()+","+puntos[i+1].coordenadas());
    }

}
```

}